# C++ regex: replace a pattern in multiple lines

Tags: regex, c++11

I'd like to remove certain lines (let's assume 'aaa' and 'bbb') from a multiline string with the standard C++ regex library. With ECMAScript replace syntax, I would use the next pattern: `/^(aaa|bbb)$/gm`. I tried to pass something like `^(aaa|bbb)$` as regex argument to `std::regex_replace`, but it's not working, as `^` and `$` seem to not get matched as the beginning and the end of line, though I didn't pass `match_not_eol` or `match_not_bol` as match flags. So how the C++ pattern should look like for this case?

Comment: Can you post something that can be copied and pasted into an online compiler?

Comment: If you downvote, care to describe, why do you think, that "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote...

Comment: Your original regex `^(aaa|bbb)$` is fine and works as expected with Boost.Regex, it's a standard defect, see [LWG issue 2343](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2343).

Comment: @Jamboree Thanks for pointing out, haven't heard about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`regex_replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/) reference does not list any flag to redefine the `^` and `$` meanings. Thus, when you need to search and replace *lines*, use the capturing group `(^|\r?\n)` before and a  lookahead `(?=\r?\n|$)` after the main pattern (and replace with backreference `$1`). Surely, the patterns can be adjusted to allow or not empty lines after the replacement.

See [IDEONE demo:](https://ideone.com/Qh1Ch9)

```
std::string s("ccc\r\naaa\r\ngggg");
std::regex ee(R"((^|\r?\n)(?:aaa|bbb)(?=\r?\n|$))");
std::string newtext = std::regex_replace( s, ee, "$1" );
std::cout << newtext << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
ccc

gggg
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I actually tried something like matching "(^|\n)" at the beginning and "($|\n)" at the end of the pattern, but it seems, that it does not match the line in case the the previous line was replaced, probably because the beginning "(^|\n)" is the part of previous match. If you replace the pattern with R"((^|\r?\n)(?:ccc|aaa|bbb)(\r?\n|$))" in your example you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: In that case, turn the trailing capture group into a lookaround. Use `std::regex ee(R"((^|\r?\n)(?:aaa|bbb)(?=\r?\n|$))");` and replace with one backreference `$1`.

Comment: If I use `(?=\r?\n|$)` it results in segfault, because the `$` is included in the lookahead, I guess, but if I use `((?=\r?\n)|$)` it's ok. Thanks for helping